# How to match 'aA1' or 'Aa1' or '1aA' with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text box and want to match the pattern as
`[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}`

```
    var x=/^[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$/;

    if(!x.test(document.getElementById('name').value))
    {
        alert("enter the correct format");
        return false;
    }
```

It works only for the value : `aA1`

what to do if 
these values can be entered randomly
like aA1, Aa1, 1aA ?

Comment: It IS possible with regex. But you are better off writing a loop for this.

Comment: kindly please tell me how to do it in Regular  expresion

Comment: does there have to be one of each?

Comment: @airza yes one of each at any position without occurence

Comment: Note (this applies to the question and all the answers so far), that `{1}` is completely redundant in a regex; it means "exactly one occurrence of the previous expression" which is exactly what the previous expression would match without any repetition modifier.

Answer (score 4):

To match a set of strings in any order you can use lookahead.  Something like this:

`/^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)[abc]{3}$/.test('cab')`

The syntax (?=whatever) is a positive lookahead, meaning it checks for a match without advancing the position of matcher.  So each group looks for your characters anywhere in the string.  The last part `[abc]{3}` ensures that no other characters are present in the string, and that there are exactly three characters.  If multiples are okay, use [abc]+ instead.

For a more detailed reference see http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html.

Comment: Without having tested it, something like this?  `/^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d).{3}$/`

Comment: @wiseguy Excellent, I'll replace the + with {3}.  Definitely want the character class there though, to weed out wrong characters.

Comment: Actually, I see that the character class is unnecessary, since the if each of the required characters is there, there can be no other characters there.  I'll leave it there, but it is optional.  It is still necessary if you are using the +

Comment: @RavinderPal I have added a link to my answer. It is more comprehensive than the answer that I gave.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the monster expression

```
/$([a-z][A-Z][0-9])|([A-Z][a-z][0-9])|([0-9][a-z][A-Z])|([a-z][0-9][A-Z])|([A-Z][0-9][a-z])|([0-9][A-Z][a-z])^/
```

but I'm not sure this is an efficient or scalable solution.

Comment: I felt kind of dirty writing it.

Comment: Btw, I think it should be `/^([a-z][A-Z][0-9]|[A-Z][a-z][0-9]|[0-9][a-z][A-Z]|[a-z][0-9][A-Z]|[A-Z][0-9][a-z]|[0-9][A-Z][a-z])$/`. The `/` are RegExp literal delimiters in JS, and `^` matches the start of the string, `$` matches the end of the string.

Comment: +1. It would be even longer if letters need to match as in OP's sample (Aa1 may mean "upper case first letter, lower case the same second letter").

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  Don't know why I put a ? mark at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
/^([a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}|[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{1}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1})$/
```

The First expression `[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}` deals with the pattern : *aA1*

The Second epression `[A-Z]{1}[a-z]{1}[0-9]{1}` deals with the pattern : *Aa1*

And the Third expression `[0-9]{1}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}` deals with the pattern : *1aA*

Comment: @airza We have this sample as asked in question aA1, Aa1, 1aA . . And the expression matches all these . .

Comment: @Wiseguy is it fine now ? ? :)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for adding a thorough explanation.